# How do I animate expansion of a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I'm looking to implement an animation that will slide open or expand a ListView in android. At the moment, I'm using a scale animation (shown below)

```
    Animation slideDown = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    slideDown.setDuration(1000);
```

but this doesn't work for 2 reasons:

1) I want the first item to fade in, and then the list to drop down. If I do a fade in animation, the entire list shows up and then jumps back up to the top and scales down to full size

2) I'm not really looking to scale, I would like to just reveal the ListView by animating down the bottom (if that makes sense).

Is there a way that I can do a TranslateAnimation on just the bottom margin or something similar? I looked into the drawable Clip resource, but that didn't seem to fit my needs here (I'm not sure how to apply it to a ListView). And I'm using a normal ListView, not an ExpandableListView, because I just have one group of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started searching for different things and it turns out that animating the height was my solution. Essentially I start with a dummy object in the list (so that it has at least 1 row), then I animate it from the height of that row to the height of the full list. Below is the code for the runnable that I am now calling.

```
private Runnable slideDownList1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        final ListView detail = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.detail_menu_1);
            ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(detail.getHeight(), detail.getHeight()*mItem.containedObjects.size());
            va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    detail.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                    detail.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            va.setDuration(1000);
            va.start();
        }
};
```

The XML is just a basic ListView with the id of detail_menu_1.

Answer (score 0):

The new element Recycler View include animations. You can use it with Support Library

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: The Recycler View looks cool, but I'm looking to animate the expansion / opening of the entire view, not of items within the view. It doesn't seem like the Recycler provides any added benefit over the ListView for animations on the view itself, from what I can see initially.

Comment: @Andrew can you clarify the comment a bit? For example, like the alarm section of clock app, it expands to show more details. Is such animation possible using RecyclerView?